# Batch insert is not working properly using spring boot, hibernate and mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I have one very annoying issue, i have read all existing documentation online and read all stackoverflow questions and answers related to this topic, but simply can not make this to work!

I am really desperate and i do not know what i am missing so i will try to give you all what i have so far. Basically what i am trying to do is to save a lot of data with one query instead of multiple queries for each object. As you can suspect i am using Spring Boot, Hibernate and MySql.

So basic facts that i have learned so far based on what i read related to "batch insert using mysql + hibernate" is next:

1. Mysql does not support Sequence ID, so i can not use it, like i could use it for PostgreSql
2. Hibernate does not support batch insert out of the box, there are couple of app properties that needs to be added

And this is what i have so far:

Application properties that i added:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:32803/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext


@Entity
data class Person (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val id: Long?,

        var firstName: String,

        var lastName: String,

        var country: String,

        var org: Int
)
```

What i want is to save a lot of Persons at once, as you can see i added batch size 50, if i understood correctly that means i will do one database hit per 50 persons while saving. (correct me if i am wrong)

And at the end i have Repository where i execute that batch insert:

```
@Repository
class PersonRepositoryCustomImpl : PersonRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private val entityManager: EntityManager? = null

    @Transactional
    override fun batchSave2(persons: Set<Person>) {
        val session = entityManager!!.unwrap(Session::class.java)


        persons.forEachIndexed { index, person ->
            if ( index % 50 == 0 ) {
                session!!.flush()
                session.clear()
            }

            session!!.save(person)
        }

        session.close()
    }

    @Transactional
    override fun <T : Person?> batchSave(entities: Collection<T>): Collection<T>? {
        val savedEntities: MutableList<T> = ArrayList(entities.size)
        var i = 0
        for (t in entities) {
            savedEntities.add(persistOrMerge(t))
            i++
            if (i % 50 == 0) { // Flush a batch of inserts and release memory.
                entityManager!!.flush()
                entityManager.clear()
            }
        }
        return savedEntities
    }

    private fun <T : Configuration?> persistOrMerge(t: T): T {
        return if (t!!.id == null) {
            entityManager!!.persist(t)
            t
        } else {
            entityManager!!.merge(t)
        }
    }
}
```

So here you can see that i have tried to make this works on 2 almost the same ways, but of course both of them seems not to work.

In order to confirm that i am actually doing batch insert i am looking at this:

https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-mysql.html

so basically that should show me queries that are being executed on DB, and there i can see that for each person object i have one insert statement.

[image]

Basically that result of this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mysql.general_log;
```

And there i can clearly see that i have multiple insert statements that do one query per object (person).

Edit:
https://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/configuring-a-datasource-proxy-in-spring-boot/

I have also implemented datasource proxy, which proved me that i am not doing batch insert:

```
Name:, Time:1, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0, Query:["insert into person(firstName, lastName, country, org) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"], Params:[(10,John,Johny,USA,ORG)]
```

i have multiple of records like this one.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: The fact that you see N queries doesn't mean Hibernate is not using batch inserts. All the queries are sent, at once, in a batch statement. Google for "JDBC batch statement" to know what a batch statement is.

Comment: How i can confirm that i am doing batch insert ? I understand that on console of application hibernate is sending one for each object, but this is log that i executed on database side

Comment: Apparently using datasource-proxy would allow doing that, if you don't trust the hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-logging

Comment: Thank you very much, i have also confirmed with this, it is making one insert per object :(

Comment: Ah, but you're using autoincrement IDs apparently. Use table generation. AFAIR,  autoincrement forces Hibernate to execute every statement separately in order to get the primary key that the database has assigned to each entity.

Comment: I have also read this: 

https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. MySQL sucks. Either you use table generation and you can use batching, or you use identity generation, and you can't. I use PostgreSQL, so I don't have this kind of problems.

Comment: Note that this article had the response from the beginning: *Even if it cannot benefit from JDBC batching*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an answer in case someone needs it:

So long story short i was not able to make MySql + hibernate batch processing work, for sake of testing i actually was able to make it work with PostgreSQL.

But anyway if anyone needs this with MySql there is a way using JDBC batch processing, and code more or less is very straight forward:

```
private String INSERT_SQL_PARAMS = "INSERT INTO item_params(p_key, p_value, item_id) values (?,?,?)"

override fun saveParams(configParams: Set<ItemParam>) {
    jdbcTemplate!!.batchUpdate(INSERT_SQL_PARAMS , configParams, 3000) { ps, argument ->
        ps.setLong(1, argument.pKey)
        ps.setString(2, argument.pValue)
        ps.setString(3, argument.itemId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't support sequences so you can generate one using this strategy in your entity class:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "voucher_sequence")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "voucher_sequence",strategy = "increment")
```

and also in your mysql url enable batching:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

and in your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

then use `saveAll()` method to persist list of entities